# How do I install will_paginate in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, will-paginate

I'm trying to install will paginate.

I installed the gem, as detailed on the github page. The gem installed OK, but when I tried a line like

```
@user = User.paginate
```

I just got an error message about the paginate method not existing.

So, I uninstalled the gem and tried using the plugin method:

```
script/plugin install svn://errtheblog.com/svn/plugins/will_paginate
```

But the above command gives no feedback whatsoever (is that normal?) and

```
script/plugin list
```

shows it hasn't installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add a `config.gem` line to `environment.rb` to load the gem?

```
config.gem 'mislav-will_paginate',
  :version => '~> 2.3.11',
  :lib => 'will_paginate',
  :source => 'http://gems.github.com'
```

And run `rake gems:install`?

Works for me.

Comment: Thanks. (How did i not see the install instructions? Doh).

Comment: Side note: if you are sharing the codebase with anyone else, it might be helpful to also run `rake gems:unpack`.  This will drop the code into your *vendors* directory and let you commit it.

Comment: That also helps quite a bit with deployment issues on shared hosts. However, I don't think this handles gems with platform-specific binary components as of yet (think mysql gem, rmagick et al)